# How to perform linear regression with numpy.polyfit and print error statistics?

Tags: numpy, best-fit

I am figuring out how to use the `np.polyfit` function and the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) confuses me. In particular, I am trying to perform linear regression and print related statistics like the sum of squared errors (SSE). Can someone provide clear and concise explanations, possibly with a minimal working example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your question. It would be nice that you showed us any code you have, just a simple example, and explain us where you struggle to print these values. Show us also any research you did, did you try anything from a web search?

Comment: thank you i think someone has answered it generically already ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.polyfit` returns a tuple containing the coefficients parametrizing the best-fitting polynomial of degree `deg`. To fit a line, use `deg = 1`. You can return the residual (sum of squared errors) by passing `full = True` as an argument to `polyfit`. Note that with this argument, `polyfit` will also return some other information about the fit, which we can just discard.

Altogether, then, we have might have something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some toy data.
x = np.random.rand(25)
y = 2 * x + 0.5 + np.random.normal(scale=0.05, size=x.size)

# Fit the trend line.
(m, b), (SSE,), *_ = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1, full=True)

# Plot the original data.
plt.scatter(x, y, color='k')

# Plot the trend line.
line_x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
plt.plot(line_x, m * line_x + b, color='r')

plt.title(f'slope = {round(m, 3)}, int = {round(b, 3)}, SSE = {round(SSE, 3)}')
plt.show()
```

The `*_` notation in the call to `polyfit` just tells Python to discard however many additional values are returned by the function. The documentation can tell you about these extra values if you're interested. We have to parse the SSE as a tuple `(SSE,)` because `polyfit` returns it as a singleton array. This code produces something like [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMAbE.png).

You might also like to know about [`np.polyval`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html), which will take tuples of polynomial coefficients and evaluate the corresponding function at input points.